# MEAN Stack NodeJS PUT requestion code is not being run

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I have created a simple booking app where using the MEAN stack. The app is working fine for the GET functionality. But for some reason my PUT code will just not run i.e. I have added console.log to try and write to the console when the PUT code runs. But this code is not being hit at all. I have tried using Postman to test if the functionality works and Postman works. See my code below:

```ts
export class Tank {

  id: string;
  date: string;
  tankNumber: number;
  sessionOne: boolean;
  sessionTwo: boolean;
  sessionThree: boolean;
  sessionFour: boolean;
  sessionFive: boolean;

  constructor(
    id: string,
    date: string,
    tankNumber: number,
    sessionOne: boolean,
    sessionTwo: boolean,
    sessionThree: boolean,
    sessionFour: boolean,
    sessionFive: boolean
  ) {
      this.id = id;
      this.date = date;
      this.tankNumber = tankNumber;
      this.sessionOne = sessionOne;
      this.sessionTwo = sessionTwo;
      this.sessionThree = sessionThree;
      this.sessionFour = sessionFour;
      this.sessionFive = sessionFive;
    }
  }
```

Below is my HTML code that sends the booking request:

```html
<mat-card *ngIf="dateSelectionButtonPressed">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Tank 1</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content *ngFor="let session of tankAvailability; let i = index">
    <div class="tank-one" *ngIf="session.tankNumber == 1">
      <button *ngIf="session.sessionOne === false" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="bookSession(session.id, session.date, session.tankNumber, session.sessionOne = true, session.sessionTwo, session.sessionThree, session.sessionFour, session.sessionFive)">07.00</button>
      <button *ngIf="session.sessionTwo === false" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="bookSession(session.id, session.date, session.tankNumber, session.sessionOne, session.sessionTwo = true, session.sessionThree, session.sessionFour, session.sessionFive)">09.00</button>
      <button *ngIf="session.sessionThree === false" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="bookSession(session.id, session.date, session.tankNumber, session.sessionOne, session.sessionTwo, session.sessionThree = true, session.sessionFour, session.sessionFive)">11.00</button>
      <button *ngIf="session.sessionFour === false" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="bookSession(session.id, session.date, session.tankNumber, session.sessionOne, session.sessionTwo, session.sessionThree, session.sessionFour = true, session.sessionFive)">13.00</button>
      <button *ngIf="session.sessionFive === false" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="bookSession(session.id, session.date, session.tankNumber, session.sessionOne, session.sessionTwo, session.sessionThree, session.sessionFour, session.sessionFive = true)">15.00</button>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Below is my booking code:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { Tank } from '../../models/tank.model';

import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { TankService } from 'src/app/services/tank.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking',
  templateUrl: './booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking.component.css']
})

export class BookingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private tankSub: Subscription;

  // public payPalConfig?: IPayPalConfig;
  selectedDate: any;
  convertedDate: string;
  dateSelectionButtonPressed = false;
  tankAvailability: Tank[] = [];
  tankOneAvailability: string[] = [];
  tank: Tank;

  constructor(private tankService: TankService) { }

  bookSession(id, date, tankNumber, sessionOne, sessionTwo, sessionThree, sessionFour, sessionFive) {
    const tank = new Tank(id, date, tankNumber, sessionOne, sessionTwo, sessionThree, sessionFour, sessionFive);
    this.tankService.updateTankWithNewBooking(tank);
  }

}
```

Below is my service for sending the Tank object along with ID to the back end server:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Tank } from '../models/tank.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TankService {
  private tanks: Tank[] = [];
  private tanksUpdate = new Subject<Tank[]>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  // Update tank with new booked session
  updateTankWithNewBooking(tank: Tank) {
    console.log(tank);
    return this.httpClient.put<{ message: string }>('http://localhost:3000/api/tank/' + tank.id, tank);
  }
}
```

Below is my backend server side NodeJS code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TankSchemaModel = require('./models/tank');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('xxxxxxx', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err + 'Connection failed!!');
  });

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
  });

  // create a tank
  app.post('/api/tank', (req, res, next) => {
    const tank = new TankSchemaModel({
      date: '22-08-2019',
      tankNumber: 1,
      sessionOne: false,
      sessionTwo: true,
      sessionThree: false,
      sessionFour: false,
      sessionFive: true
      /* date: req.body.date,
      tankNumber: req.body.tankNumber,
      sessionOne: req.body.sessionOne,
      sessionTwo: req.body.sessionTwo,
      sessionThree: req.body.sessionThree,
      sessionFour: req.body.sessionFour,
      sessionFive: req.body.sessionFive */
    });
    // save tank to database
    tank.save().then(createdTankDetails => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Tank detals created successfully!',
        tankId: createdTankDetails._id
      });
    });
  });

  // get all tank data
  app.get('/api/tanks', (req, res, next) => {
    TankSchemaModel.find().then(documents => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Tank data fetched successfully',
        tanks: documents
      });
    });
  });

  // get tank data by date
  app.get('/api/tanks/:date', (req, res, next) => {
    TankSchemaModel.find( { date: { $eq: req.params.date } } ).then(documents => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Tank details successfully fetched!',
        tanks: documents
      });
    });
  });

  // edit a tank
  app.put('/api/tank/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Beans!");
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.date);
    TankSchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          // _id: req.body.id,
          date: req.body.date,
          tankNumber: req.body.tankNumber,
          sessionOne: req.body.sessionOne,
          sessionTwo: req.body.sessionTwo,
          sessionThree: req.body.sessionThree,
          sessionFour: req.body.sessionFour,
          sessionFive: req.body.sessionFive
        }
      }, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Tank booking failed!'
          });
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Tank booking updated successfully!'
          });
        }
      });
    });



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: You don't appear to *subscribe* to the observable anywhere.

Comment: Should the backend NodeJS code still run though i.e. I would expect text "Beans" to still be written to the console when the PUT request is code is ran?

Comment: Looks like I was being a noob. Yeh that worked. Thanks for your help Jon :-)